# Angular constant & injection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, razor

[image]We are using ASP.NET MVC in conjunction with AngularJS.
De views are rendered through razor and we also have T4MVC.

There is a javascript file which defines a module with routing.
The templateUrl needs to come from Razor.
So the Razor file references the javascript file and needs to pass on the URL's based on T4MVC (C# values).

What is the best way to do this ?
Do we need to use the Angular constant mechanism? 
Will these constant values be injected through the factory function ?

Is there a more intelligent mechanism ?

Attached you find a print screen which doesn't work.

Comment: can't inject a service to config. If it was me would use a window namespaced variable and skip the constant. Also no need to wrap angular in `$(function()`

Comment: I agree with charlietfl. Provide an API to register your URLs (outside of angular) - a window namespaced variable would work nicely for this.

Comment: But he is trying to inject a constant. I believe you can inject constants and providers in the config block.

Comment: @Edminsson That's true, it is likely the $(function(){}) enclosure that is causing the issue. It does not get executed until some later point.

Comment: Yes @pixelbits I also think that the jQuery ready function could be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.

The reason that it didn't work was the document ready function of Jquery.

I changed it to this construction:
 (function () {

} ());